# Issue with simple SQL statement / PHP function not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple function to write into my database.  This is the error I am getting.

This is the error I am getting

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/MySQLDao.php on line 92 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/MySQLDao.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/createCommunity.php(26): MySQLDao->createCommunity('radowns82@gmail...', 'YGHFYG', 'Endcliffe') #1 {main} thrown in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/MySQLDao.php on line 92

This is the initial PHP script that calls it:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$code = htmlentities($_POST["code"]);
$communityname = htmlentities($_POST["communityname"]);

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao -> openConnection();

$result = $dao -> createCommunity($email, $code, $communityname);

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

This is MySQLDao.php

```
<?php

class MySQLDao{

var $dbhost = null;
var $dbuser = null;
var $dbpass = null;
var $conn = null;
var $dbname = null;
var $result = null;

public function __construct(){
    $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
    $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
    $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
    $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
}

public function openConnection()
{
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        echo new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");

}

public function getConnection()
{
echo ("2");
    return $this->conn;
}

public function closeConnection()
    {
    if($this->conn!=null)
        $this->conn->close();
}

public function getUserDetails($email)
{
    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "select * from users where user_email='".$email."'";

    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
        $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row)){
            $returnValue = $row;
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;

}

public function getUserDetailsWithPassword($email, $userPassword)
{
    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "select id, user_email, user_name from users where user_email = '".$email."' and user_password = '".$userPassword."'";

    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 )){
        $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row)){
            $returnValue = $row;
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;
}

public function registerUser($email, $password, $username)
{
    $sql = "insert into users set user_email=?,user_password=?,user_name=?";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    if(!$statement)
        throw new Exception($statement->error);

    $statement->bind_param("sss", $email, $password, $username);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute();

    return $returnValue;
}

public function createCommunity($email, $code, $communityname)
{
    $sql = "insert into communities set email=?,code=?,communityname=?";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

if(!$statement){
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
}
    $statement->bind_param("sss", $email, $code, $communityname);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute();

    return $returnValue;
}


}

?>
```

That 'communities' table also has an 'id' column (1st column) which I am not posting to as I thought it would auto-populate and increment... maybe this is where I am going wrong?

Comment: Maybe your '$this->conn is null. Check that or show us more code.

Comment: You're checking if `$statement` is false, so it wouldn't be an object. Check for mysqli_error on your connection instead.

Comment: Post the full `MySQLDao` class

Comment: the connection $this->conn definitely works fine, as other functions are contained within that MySQLDao.php file.

Comment: Use `throw new Exception($this->conn->error);`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @RIggsFolly It came up with an error that indicated that the field in the database didn't match up with the sql statement. Cheers everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection fails first you need to know why so show the actual database error. and second, there is very little point in continuing the scripts execution without a connection to the database.

So can I suggest this change to your  `openConnection()` method

Also if you think there is any chance of something wrong in the MSYQLI code these 4 lines will basically ensure you get told about any errors, while you are developing, specially if you are developing on a live server with ERROR REPORTING turned off.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


public function openConnection()
{
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, 
                             $this->dbpass, $this->dbname
                            );
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {   
        echo 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' - '
        . $mysqli->connect_error;
        exit;
    }
}
```